# Query to select data from database between 2 timestamps, Exception: time_bucket function does not exists?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, timescaledb

I've been trying to write a query in Java to select data from postgres timescale database between 2 timestamps, but I keep getting Exception says that time_bucket function does not exists

I cannot change the timestamp column in database to Date since I dont have the ownership, and I tried to copy paste the query to sql editor, it works perfectly fine!!

this is the query:

```
private final String SELECT_CANDLESTICK_BY_REQUEST = "SELECT " + 
        "   time_bucket(  interval '1 minute' , period_start_ts) AS periodts,  " + 
        "   count(*),  " + 
        "   first(metrics->>'askOpen',period_start_ts) as askOpen,  " + 
        "   max(metrics->>'askHigh') as askHigh,  " + 
        "   min(metrics->>'askLow') as askLow,  " + 
        "   last(metrics->>'askClose',period_start_ts) as askClose, " + 
        "   first(metrics->>'bidOpen',period_start_ts) as bidOpen,  " + 
        "   max(metrics->>'bidHigh') as bidHigh,  " + 
        "   min(metrics->>'bidLow') as bidLow,  " + 
        "   last(metrics->>'bidClose',period_start_ts) as bidClose " + 
        "  FROM candlestick_1_sec_fact " + 
        "  where period_start_ts between ? and ? " + 
        "  and symbol_cd = ? and liquidity_source_nm =  ? " + 
        "  GROUP BY periodts " + 
        "  ORDER BY periodts" ;
```

this is how i set the parameters:

```
PreparedStatement select = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_CANDLESTICK_BY_REQUEST);


    select.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(startTime));
    select.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(endTime));
    select.setString(3, symbol);
    select.setString(4, source);
```

this is the exception i get:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function time_bucket(interval, timestamp without time zone) does not exist . Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Even if i take out the interval keyword in the query, it still does not recognize the time_bucket function.

Thank you in advance for your time and knowledge!

Comment: Which version of timescaledb are you using? Are you sure that you are allowed to access the function? Also, are you by chance using a different schema or is the extension installed at a different schema?

Comment: I can insert into this table, so its not about my jdbc configuration and schema, and I copy pasted the query to sql edior, it works just fine...

Comment: Can you add the output of the following query executed via JDBC and the correct user? `SELECT n.nspname, p.proname, a.rolname, pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid), p.proacl
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (n.oid = p.pronamespace) LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_authid a ON (a.oid = p.proowner)
WHERE pg_catalog.pg_function_is_visible(p.oid) AND p.proname = 'time_bucket'
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4;`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I finally solved the problem, its because I have set my default schema in my jdbc configuration file, but time_bucket function is in different schema, so system somehow cannot find it----which is weird, but that's the cause. again, thank you for your answer and help!

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Repeating the answer from the comments for easier retrieval:

If you have a default schema (aka search path) set it must include the schema that contains the TSDB functions.

On a live connection you can do this e.g. like this:

```sql
SET search_path TO demo, public;
```